# web.config problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, web-config

I have a question about MS webservices and web.config configuration.

I have a solution with two projects inside :

- Webservice ws_A a
- Website web_A

My website is connected to my website with "Web References" from Visual Studio. My webservice is connected to my database by :

```
public static SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(myString);
```

In my webservice, I retrieve a connectionstring from webservice web.config with this method :

```
String sa = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bdd"].ConnectionString;
```

I call the webservice via the website (WebReferences) and retrieve some informations from it.

But in order to retrieve the string in webservice, I need to declare this string in the website web.config. It is not logical because only the webservice need this string in order to save datas in database.

If I do not declare the string in the website web.config, I have a nullReferenceException in the webservice.

Anyone knows this problem and a solution in order to avoid to put the ConnectionString in the website ? It must don't know the database existance !

EDIT :
To use my webservice, I do this in the website :

```
WebService1.WS_A webservice = new WebService1.WS_A();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're saying that's not possible currently. The website is actually hosting the web service. So you are required to have all configuration in the web.config of the website.

If you don't want the website to have the connection string to the database, at this point you need to create a separate project to HOST the web service. You can then configure the database connection inside that separate project and it will completely unknown to the first website.

At this point you will be truly using a webservice instead of creating a fancy service that's self hosted and doesn't buy you anything over a simple class.

Comment: Not sure to understand. Why the website si hosting the webservice ? I only created an instance of webservice in the website !

Comment: A webservice does not stand on it's own. It requires a hosting container, the most common hosting containers are web application projects. It's also possible to host from inside of a Windows Service for internal hosting. Is your web service hosted in a separate web application or windows service?

Comment: The goal is to have a webservice on a distant server (in IIS) and some clients wich will connect to it by the WSDL file (in order to call method from webservice). The WSDL is imported in client code.

Comment: Correct. That web server is required to have a web application project that contains the web service. The same web app will have the configuration for said service, including connection strings. At this point when you consume the WSDL the callers of the service have no idea about the existence of the database or connection string because that's part of the web.config of the hosting web app.

Comment: So if I understand properly, when I will put my webservice in IIS, the problem will disappear ?

Comment: Yes, with the service hosted in IIS any one that wishes to invoke it needs to consume the WSDL, everything that's behind the WSDL is protected from external access. As far as people outside of your solution can tell there's nothing to it except the WSDL. The WSDL is the service contract which specifies that the services does X Y and Z, that's it and nothing else. So as long as your webservice doesn't have a GetConnectionString() method that returns the string OVER the service you should be good to go.

Comment: After the test, I can confirm the exception doesn't exist anymore. Do you know the difference between Web Reference and Service Reference ? How avoid to share web.config if two webservices are on the same IIS server ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior, because the webservice will run in the context of the web application and hence it will access the configuration file of the web application.
The same if you have a dataaccess layer that connection to the database, you can use the dataaccess with web application or windows application or console appliction or..., so the dataaccess will access the configuration file of the project that it runs in its context.

Comment: Not sure to understand but how avoid it ? I want only the webservice is the unique entity which knows the connectionstring.

Comment: Can you replace your web service with a WCF service?
If so, you can add the connectionstring only in the wcf project.

Answer (score 0):

Each project only has access to its own configuration resources, and cannot access the other project's config resources. So, if you need to instantiate your web service with a connection string (not sure why that's necessary, but I digress...) from your website using a stored connection string, then the connection string needs to be available as a resource to the website.

Again I'm still not certain why it's necessary for you to call your web service with a connection string, as I use both ASMX and WCF services and I've never had to provide a connection string on the client proxy in order to call the service.

However, I must admit that my experience with the various config/setup options for web services in .NET is relatively limited, so I'm in no way ruling out the fact that it might be necessary in your case to instantiate your client proxy with a connection string.

Comment: It's not this king of problem. I have the webservice wich use a database and a website wich use the webservice. To connect to my database, I put a connectionString in the webservice web.config. To connect the website to the webservice, I use the Web Reference system from Visual Studio. But if I don't put this connectionString in the website web.config, an exception appears and the webservice can't connect to the database.